# Android Studio Fragments Math Calculation

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm programming just for fun and try to teach myself java in connection with Android Studios.
Because I have an App Drawer I need fragments (this is my current state of knowledge). 
see photo [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCvTi.jpg)
The problem is that I can't use `findViewById` to get my numbers from the input. see photo 
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXejU.jpg)

But I need them for my calculations.

Do you have a suggestion?
Do you have examples how I can execute a mathematical calculation in a fragment?

Comment: why you can't use findViewById to get numbers ?

Comment: I can't use findby... in a fragment. Or is it?

Comment: To find id you just need to call `view.findViewById()` under `onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)` of fragment

Comment: Ok tks. I will try it later

Answer (score 0):

you can use findViewById() but you need to get the view object

you need to use it something like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, 
                         ViewGroup container, 
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testclassfragment, container, false);
     EditText edittext1 = (EditText ) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
     EditText edittext2 = (EditText ) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
     EditText edittext3 = (EditText ) view.findViewById(R.id.edittext3);
     TextView answer = (TextView ) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_ans);
     int a=Integer.parseInt(edittext1.getText());
     int b=Integer.parseInt(edittext2.getText());
     int c=Integer.parseInt(edittext3.getText());
     int ans=a+b+c; //for example 
     answer.setText(""+ans);



     return view;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example to use this with my calculator and numbers?

Comment: could you give what operations do you want to perform? I don't understand the language of the app

Comment: I program a gasoline cost calculator. 
 
This calculator should calculate the cost of my car for a certain distance. 
 
Another point can calculate for example the average consumption.

So you have different possibilities to calculate the consumption, costs and distance mathematically.

Comment: what are the values of the three edittext? what do those fields mean?

Comment: X+y+z=number. For example

Comment: hey, check out the answer. i've made a few edits. let me know if this helps your case